# Needs clarity on hibernate second level cache

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, memcached

I need some clarification with the Hibernate second level cache.

1. How does the hibernate second level cache works?
2. Does it loads all the data from the tables for which there is @Cacheable annotation (with respect to hibernate annotation) in the entity classes on server start up in the Java EE environment?
3. Will the cache gets sync up when there is an update on those tables and how?
4. Last one is there any ways for my DAO code to get notified when there is an updated on some table which i am interested upon? (Looking for any listener which can intimate abt the updates of the tables).

Answer (score 2):

1. *How does the hibernate second level cache works?*

   When your entity is marked as cacheable and if you have configured the second level cache then hibernate will cache the entity to the second level cache after the first read.

   Hibernate provides the flexibility to plugin any cache implementation that follows hibernates specification. Refer [Hibernate Manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch20.html#performance-cache) for more details on second level cache and configurations options.
2. *Does it loads all the data from the tables for which there is @Cacheable annotation (with respect to hibernate annotation) in the entity classes on server start up in the Java EE environment?*

   I don't think there is any configuration for achieving this. Indirectly you can achieve this by reading the entire table in startup, this can adversely affect the system startup time. *(i don't prefer this)*. If the entity is modified externally, then hibernate can't sync it and you will end up getting stale data.
3. *Will the cache gets sync up when there is an update on those tables and how?*

   The cache won't get updated instantly after the table update. The subsequent call to fetch the updated record will go the database, hibernate achieves this internally by using session timestamps.
4. Last one is there any ways for my DAO code to get notified when there is an updated on some table which i am interested upon? (Looking for any listener which can intimate abt the updates of the tables).

   No, hibernate doesn't support this.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer.

So there should be an explicit cal ever time to read the updated data  from the table and hibernate intern update the cache internally?

I am using second level cache in my application with "Show_SQL = true" in the cfg.xml file, Which prints the query whenever i call the same method multiple time. Does it mean it just print the query on the console, but it fetch data from cache?

Is there anyways to verify or check from where the data is fetched (whether from db or cache)?

Comment: If it displays SQL, it's executing it. If you're executing a query, and not just calling `Session.get()` or navigating a toOne association, then it will always execute a SQL query, unless the query itself is cachable and the query cache is enabled.

Comment: I have not enabled the query cache in my application and i am using mostly hql query. It executes the query on every time i make a call to a same method - it means every time it hits the database to get the data r8t?
But when i printing the time taken on every iteration it keeps decreasing. That's why i am getting confused whether data is pulled from DB or cache

Comment: Yes, it goes to the database each time. Buta databases are fast because they also have caches, optimizations, etc. That's why you see decreasing times.

Comment: If you have set "hibernate.show_sql" to "true", you will always see the query printed. In order to verify whether the data comes from cache/ database,you may need to rely on cache statistics through JMX. 1. Enable statistics in your cahce , refer to [Ehcache Documentation](http://ehcache.org/documentation/user-guide/jmx#performance).  2. Register CacheStatistics in the platform MBean server, refer [Ehcache Documentation](http://ehcache.org/documentation/user-guide/jmx#JConsole-Example).

Comment: To add data into second level can we able to use only **Session.load()** and **session.get()** method only? Is there any methods which returns multiple records which are stored into second level cache automatically, as I want to load lookup table data into second level cache which has multiple rows.

Answer (score 0):

1. That's a too broad question to be answered here.
2. No. It populates the cache lazily. Each time you get a cachable entity from the database, using the hibernate API or a query, this entity is stored in the cache. Later, when `session.get()` is called with an ID of an entity that is in the cache, no database query is necessary.
3. If the update is made through Hibernate, then the cache is updated. If it's done using an external application, or a SQL query, or even a bulk update HQL query, then the cache is unaware of the update. That's why you need to be careful about which entities you make cachable, which time-to-live you choose, etc. Sometimes, returning stale values is not problematic, and sometimes it is unacceptable.
4. No.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Only when i make a query by ID on the second time it tries to get data from the cache rather than database?

I am using second level cache in my application with "Show_SQL = true" in the cfg.xml file, Which prints the query whenever i call the same method multiple time. Does it mean it just print the query on the console, but it fetch data from cache?

Is there anyways to verify or check from where the data is fetched (whether from db or cache)?

Comment: Yes, the cache is only used when accessing the entities by ID (with `session.get()` or by navigating through a toOne association)